# SQL query the last created item performance

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I am trying to fetch the last created item in a large table like this:

```
SELECT `raw_detection`.* FROM `raw_detection`  
WHERE `raw_detection`.`duplicated` = 0 
AND `raw_detection`.`audio_source_id` = 100  
ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1
```

But this query takes a long time to run (more than 2 seconds).

I have this index:

```
  KEY `index_raw_detections_audio_source`(`audio_source_id`,`duplicated`,`created_at`)
```

Is there any better way to fetch the last created item for a specific audio source?

Comment: Do you really need to use `SELECT *`?. Any way, your query seems like the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your key references three columns. It cannot be used to speed up queries using only the `created_at` portion of the key. Try creating an additional key for just `created_at`.

For reference, from the MySQL doc:

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on
>
> (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).
>
> MySQL cannot use the index to perform lookups if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: I already have index by only created_at, but in this case I have another problem, it scans the whole table trying to find the audio_source_id. It doesn't help.

Comment: No.  That 3-column is excellent.  The first 2 columns handle all the `WHERE`, leaving the 3rd column to perform the `ORDER BY`.  I do not know why it took so long.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score -2):

In your select, specify the columns needed rather than doing select *